# Where is the error in this code? java for NetBeans IDE 8.2 RC

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans, ide

\ \ where The problem in here

```
public static void displaySum(int x , int y) {
    System.out.println("Sum of %d and %d is %d ",x,y,x+y);   
}
```

/*   -----*/

```
    public static int dispalySum(int x , int y ){
    System.out.println("First number is %.2f \n" + x );
    System.out.println("Second number is %.2f \n" + y );
    System.out.println("Sum is %.2f \n" + x+y );
    return x+y;
}
```

/*--------------*/

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num1 = 3;
    int num2 = 2;
    displaySum(num1,num2);
}
```

### }

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTHY {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

//What can I do in here ?

```
    UcakRezervasyonSistemi thyRezervasyonSistemi = new UcakRezervasyonSistemi(5);
```

/*????????*/

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputKey = "c";

    while(inputKey.equals("c" )|| inputKey.equals("C")){
        thyRezervasyonSistemi.rezervasyonAl();
        System.out.println("\nDevam etmek için c'ye, çıkmak için herhangi başka bir tuşa basınız ");
        inputKey = input.next();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and provide significantly more details in your question. You've provided three snippets of code, but you haven't told us what you expect it to do or what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrong way to write the int data type function.
use: print(displaySum(num1,num2));

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println()` method does not support formatting. Try the following:

```
public static void displaySum(int x , int y) 
{
    System.out.printf("Sum of %d and %d is %d ",x,y,x+y);   
}
```

or also:

```
public static void displaySum(int x , int y) 
{
    System.out.format("Sum of %d and %d is %d ",x,y,x+y);   
}
```